# Can a magnetic field weaken aluminum?

Tags: magnetic-fields, stress-strain, metals

I'm wondering if there is any reason to suspect that applying a magnetic field to a piece of solid aluminum would weaken it structurally in any way.

The application is that I would like to put a stir bar in an aluminum vessel to mix the contents. Putting aside any question of mechanical wear from the stir bar itself, could the long-term (years) application of a magnetic field affect the integrity of the metal?

Comment: Not a chance. At least not with the kinds of magnetic fields that you will be able to generate in a stirring mixer.